# Shorten queries with multiple joins

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, join, conditional-aggregation

Is there a way to shorten this query?
This query returns the result I want but I feel like this is to long. Are there tips to make an efficient query wilth miltiple joins?

```
SELECT home.team_id, home.name, ((home.hwins+away.awins)*1.0/(home.hwins+away.awins+draw.nowin)) as winratio
FROM(
    SELECT m.home_team_api_id AS team_id, t.team_long_name AS name, COUNT(m.id) as hwins
    FROM match m
    LEFT JOIN team t
        ON m.home_team_api_id=t.team_api_id
    WHERE m.home_team_goal > m.away_team_goal
    GROUP BY m.home_team_api_id) AS home
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT m.away_team_api_id AS team_id, t.team_long_name AS name, COUNT(m.id) as awins
    FROM match m
    LEFT JOIN team t
        ON m.away_team_api_id=t.team_api_id
    WHERE m.away_team_goal > m.home_team_goal
    GROUP BY m.away_team_api_id) AS away
    ON home.team_id=away.team_id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT m.away_team_api_id AS team_id, t.team_long_name AS name, COUNT(m.id) as nowin
    FROM match m
    LEFT JOIN team t
        ON m.away_team_api_id=t.team_api_id
    WHERE m.away_team_goal = m.home_team_goal
    GROUP BY m.away_team_api_id) AS draw
    ON home.team_id=away.team_id
GROUP BY home.team_id
ORDER BY winratio DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The result:

| team_id | name | winratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8634 | FC Barcelona | 0.8897338403041825 |
| 8633 | Real Madrid CF | 0.8871595330739299 |
| 9925 | Celtic | 0.8825910931174089 |
| 9823 | FC Bayern Munich | 0.8693693693693694 |
| 10260 | Manchester United | 0.8687782805429864 |
| 9885 | Juventus | 0.8669724770642202 |
| 9772 | SL Benfica | 0.8644859813084113 |
| 9773 | FC Porto | 0.8632075471698113 |
| 8593 | Ajax | 0.861904761904762 |
| 9931 | FC Basel | 0.861244019138756 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, according to which you count only when there's a satisfied condition. This will avoid you to have three subqueries.

```
SELECT team_id, name, ((hwins+awins)*1.0/(hwins+awins+nowin)) as winratio
FROM(SELECT m.home_team_api_id                                     AS team_id, 
            t.team_long_name                                       AS name, 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN m.home_team_goal > m.away_team_goal
                       THEN m.id END)                              AS hwins,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN m.away_team_goal > m.home_team_goal
                       THEN m.id END)                              AS awins,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN m.away_team_goal = m.home_team_goal
                       THEN m.id END)                              AS nowin
     FROM      match m
     LEFT JOIN team t
            ON m.home_team_api_id=t.team_api_id
     GROUP BY m.home_team_api_id, t.team_long_name
     ) AS all_matches
ORDER BY winratio DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Or if you wish to do it without subqueries:

```
SELECT m.home_team_api_id                                     AS team_id, 
       t.team_long_name                                       AS name, 
       (COUNT(CASE WHEN m.home_team_goal <> m.away_team_goal 
                   THEN m.id END) *0.1) / COUNT(*)            AS winratio
FROM      match m
LEFT JOIN team t
       ON m.home_team_api_id=t.team_api_id
GROUP BY m.home_team_api_id, t.team_long_name
```

**Note**: You're missing some fields in your aggregation, and the final outer `GROUP BY` is not needed. In general you want to use this clause only when you're using aggregate functions.